# Почему выдает Unexpected token? Javascript

Tags: javascript

Консоль выдает Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' на счет 14 строки. Почему?

```js
var whichVariable = 0;
var whichOne = fucntion(whichVariable) {
 if (whichVariable === 0) {
 return "First word:"
 }
 if (whichVariable === 1) {
 return "Second word:"
 }
 return "Third word:"
 };
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
 var hobby = prompt("Describe yourself in 3 words! " + whichOne(whichVariable));
 $("body").append("<p>" + hobby + "</p>");
 whichVariable++;
 };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Опечатка в слове `function`.

```js
var whichVariable = 0;
var whichOne = function(whichVariable) {
  if (whichVariable === 0) {
    return "First word:"
  }
  if (whichVariable === 1) {
    return "Second word:"
  }
  return "Third word:"
};
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var hobby = prompt("Describe yourself in 3 words! " + whichOne(whichVariable));
  $("body").append("<p>" + hobby + "</p>");
  whichVariable++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```